# How do I upload / access a .env file for a contact form on a Heroku hosted web app?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

I'm creating a website currently for a client who requires a contact form on her site. The contact form is compiled using Nodemailer in a Node.js back-end. It functions absolutely fine on my localhost when it's running on my local server, however I can't upload the files to Heroku as the email credentials are stored in a .env file, and accessed within my app.js as:

```
process.env.EMAIL
process.env.PASSWORD
```

I'm wanting to store the credentials in a .env file obviously for security, and also so I can show the code as part of my portfolio on my GitHub. The .env file is currently within my GitIgnore file.

How do I get the .env file (or its contents) to upload so it actually functions on the internet, without exposing the email/password? Any help for a novice would be appreciated!!

Comment: On Heroku website under your App Settings you can set your environment variables.

Comment: So you can - do I need to store them in a string with quotation marks or can they just be plain?

Comment: without quotation marks

Comment: OK - the documentation doesn't mention anything about changing my code... Do I have to change my env code in my app.js? I've added the variables but the form still isn't working so assume there's something I'm missing. Thanks.